# website is coming with "/> before website starts

Tags: php, wordpress

```
My website is WordPress based and before website starts its coming with a code
"/>  what should I do?
[Check this photo at top right corner][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBrCe.jpg
```

**And Code Is :**

```
<?php
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
    if( $_GET && key_exists('mfn-rtl', $_GET) ):
        echo '<html class="no-js" lang="ar" dir="rtl">';
    else:
?>
<html class="no-js<?php echo mfn_user_os(); ?>" <?php language_attributes(); ?><?php mfn_tag_schema(); ?>>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- head -->
<head>
<!-- meta -->
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<?php 
    if( mfn_opts_get('responsive') ){
        if( mfn_opts_get('responsive-zoom') ){
            echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />';

        } else {
            echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />';
        }    
    }
?>
```

Its just wordpress theme header file.**BeTheme**
I had posted half code which I edited and then i removed that code 
It was nothing but meta description.

Comment: Post your code. A screenshot does not help. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The code is nothing but theme header file. Actually initially I was adding meta description through Appearance ->Edit Option ->Theme Header.But I just added code and then removed it suddenly it was showing that error mentioned above. Here is the website Link : https://abulhasanalinadwi.org/

Comment: I never knew you could use ":" instead of braces in if/then/else in php.. (after the DOCTYPE tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever is generating the meta descriptions is doing it wrong.     If you view source in firefox the meta descriptions line comes up in red, you'll see that it has two 'content' specs and a trailing " />.   THis is highly likely where the problem is coming from.  If not in your theme header, then from any plugins that may be attempting to modify the meta tags.

[image]

```
<meta name="description" content="<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="66CB0E32331B0DD5F0158BB3791C8F23" />" />
```